# How do I write a bash script that goes through each directory executes a command in each directory

Tags: bash

How do I write a bash script that traverses each directory (~100) within a parent folder and executes a command like ./xxxx.exe?

My question is:

```
{#!bin/bash
cd directory_A
gfortran -w xxxx.f90 -o xxxx.exe;
./xxxx.exe;

cd ..

cd directory_B
./xxxx.exe;

cd ..

cd directory_C
./xxxx.exe;
cd ..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find with -execdir and so:

```
find /pathtoparentdirectory -type d -execdir ./xxxx.exe
```

Search for all directory in the parent directory and then execute xxxx.exe from within each found directory.